# loading Jasper report from Jdeveloper

Tags: java, jdeveloper

```
I got a exception when running jasper report form Jdeveloper from WebLogic, as it works fine when from integratedWebLogicServer (the report loaded normally).
```

I checked many times and have no errors un logic mistaks in my code, it seems that the weblogic cannot get the real path
Please advise how I can solve this issue.
please check the below exception and my code

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.File.(File.java:277)
 at tb.tasksystem.view.Servlets.RepServlet.doPost(RepServlet.java:117)
 at tb.tasksystem.view.Servlets.RepServlet.doGet(RepServlet.java:72)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
 at

Comment: Obviously the code at tb.tasksystem.view.Servlets.RepServlet.doPost(RepServlet.java:117) at is the problem. My guess is that the path is only valid on the development machine, but not on the server.